# C run time library

Tags: windows, operating-system, runtime

What exactly is a C Run time library and who puts in the `_mainCRTStartup()` function into our code and why is it needed?

Answer (score 1):

The C runtime library does two things: it implements the documented functions that you can call from your C program, and it contains support code that is used invisibly by the compiler behind the scenes. `_mainCRTStartup` is an example of behind-the-scenes support - it is called *before* your `main` function is called to do things like parse the command line.